# How to fill input type file with external image if I have link on this image?

Tags: javascript, html, upload

I have the following input:

```
  <input path="multipartFile" name="file" type="file" class="file" />
```

On ui I see button. When I click on this I see file selector and can select file I want.

When file selected I can catch event:

```
$('.file').change(function(){...})
```

Now I want fill this input using another way. I have external image link and I want push it there.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Simple answer, no. You cannot programmatically set the value for the `file` input. Your alternative is to use the image link you have as (say) background image for a div and show the `file` input as a related control

Comment: @Jibi Abraham Can you show example?